# Python Keyerror even through the key exists

Tags: python-3.x, function, keyerror

Below is a function that I have written to fetch a specific value from a url using the requests library. The idea is to return both the value name and value unique id if present else say it is not present.

Under the try section, the word bcc gets to store a dictionary(which is a json output). The dictionary looks something like this

```
{'records': [{'uuid': '1cbb7288-b828-11e9-a419-11a032324a29', 'name': '1234_192.168.6.144/24'}, {'uuid': 'c523ef30-b823-1123-a619-00avaei7a29', 'name': '1342_172.26.41.10/28'}], 'num_records': 2}
```

No matter what, I keep getting the below KeyError. The key does exist and when I test run it manually on the python prompt it works fine. But doesn't work when I import it from the file into another python file under another function.

Appreciate if someone can help me understand what is going on here.

```
>>> from filers import NC
>>> NC.broadcastcheck(cluster,'1243',headers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/python/filer.py", line 65, in broadcastcheck
    def broadcastcheck(cluster, vlan, headers):
KeyError: 'num_records'
```

This is the function I have written.

```
   def broadcastcheck(cluster, vlan, headers):
      url = 'https://'+cluster+'/api/ethernet/broadcast-domains'
      pattern = re.compile(r'^[^_]+(?=_)')
      try:
         bcc = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False).json()
         for i in range(bcc['num_records']):
            bcdname = bcc['records'][i]['name']
            bcduuid = bcc['records'][i]['uuid']
            matches = pattern.finditer(bcdname)
            for match in matches:
               return "present",bcdname,bcduuid if match.group(0) == vlan else "notpresent"
      except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
         print(str(error))
         sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: `bcc` inside `broadcastcheck` must not be what you expect. Put several prints after `bcc` is assigned and really verify it. If you're getting a key error, the key does not exist at the level that you expect it to. Verify that there isn't another wrapper over the data you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case I was extracting data from an API response, the API as receving two parameters are page_num and per_page, I set the page num to range from 1-10, and per page to 10000, when the loop was getting an empty response 'let's say at page 10 we don't have data', the error appears, I solved it by checking the response legth before attempting to read the key I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return of the ".json()". It may bring the results inside of an object called "data".

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? This answer is vague.

Comment: Yeah me too. I don't understand where is the object called data in my code.

Comment: The request().get().json() method can return the response inside an object data, check the return of the request().get().json() to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about this. It looks like the API link was the issue. It didn't return the expected value. Now it does and it works properly.